# 最初からクラウドプラクティショナーではなく、AWS SAAの資格を勉強しても大丈夫でしょうか？

Tags: aws

AWSの資格を取得しようと思っているのですが、最初からAWS SAAの資格を勉強しても大丈夫でしょうか?　　クラウドプラクティショナーから学習した方がいいでしょうか?!
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

資格取得と学習とが混同されていますが、どちらが目的でしょうか？

念のため、AWSでは[ロールベースのパス](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/training/learning-paths/)を定義しています。

- [クラウドプラクティショナー](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/training/path-cloudpractitioner/)
  AWS クラウドを使用して仕事をしている技術、管理、営業、購買、財務などを担当している方に有用です。
- [アーキテクト](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/training/path-architecting/)
  ソリューションアーキテクト、ソリューション設計エンジニア、および AWS でのアプリケーション設計やシステム設計を学びたいすべての人を対象としています。

とロールとしては別であり、資格取得としても前段に受けるべきものというわけではなさそうです。

またアーキテクトを見るとわかりますが、SAA資格試験の前段に

1. AWS Technical Essentials
2. Architecting on AWS

の研修が用意されています。学習が目的であればArchitecting on AWSを受講され、その前提知識として必要となるAWSの基礎知識を学びたいのであれば、AWS Technical Essentialsの受講を検討されたらいいかと思います。